# Angular datatables Fixed Columns undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datatable, angular-datatables

I used [angular datatables with fixed column](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/withFixedColumns), my HTML code for view as the following:

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="PerformanceCtrl">
  <table  id="example" datatable="" 
          class="stripe row-border order-column" 
          dt-options="dtOptions">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger</td>
            <td>Nixon</td>
        </tr>
   </tbody> 
 </table>
```

And my controller code as the following:

```
'use strict';

app.controller('PerformanceCtrl', ['$scope', 'DTOptionsBuilder', 'DTColumnDefBuilder', function ($scope, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnDefBuilder) {

$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
    .withOption('scrollY', '300px')
    .withOption('scrollX', '100%')
    .withOption('scrollCollapse', true)
    .withOption('paging', false)
    .withFixedColumns({
        leftColumns: 1
    });

}]);
```

And for my `index.html` file, I included datatables libraries as the following order:

```
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="modules/performance/controller.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-datatables/dist/plugins/bootstrap/datatables.bootstrap.css">
<script src="bower_components/DataTables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-datatables/dist/angular-datatables.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-datatables/dist/plugins/fixedheader/angular-datatables.fixedheader.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-datatables/dist/plugins/fixedcolumns/angular-datatables.fixedcolumns.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bower_components/DataTables/media/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
```

And This my module:

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['datatables', 'datatables.fixedcolumns']);
```

But I got this error `undefined is not a function` as this image:

[image: Undefined is not a function]

If I removed the following code from options of table, No error but no fixedColumns:

```
.withFixedColumns({
        leftColumns: 1
    });
```

I need to make my first column fixed, How can I fix this error ?

Comment: Please check this ;ine `angular.module('showcase.withFixedColumns', ['datatables', 'datatables.fixedcolumns'])` . have you inject this `datatables.fixedcolumns'` ?

Comment: @RameshRajendran Yes, I injected it, I add my module in Question

Comment: I think i have fount your issue by my answer. please let me know, if you have doubt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I post this question on [github](https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/issues/384#issuecomment-124498552), and l-lin answer on it.

I missed including the following:

```
<script src="vendor/FixedColumns-3.0.4/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/FixedColumns-3.0.4/css/dataTables.fixedColumns.min.css">
```

I should download the [FixColumns](https://github.com/DataTables/FixedColumns) jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You just forgot to add the `ng` attribute to the datatables.

Below is working Screen shot  ...

[image]

Click [here for Live Demo](http://[demo][1])

Comment: The demo link not working with me, and I added `ng` attribute, and `ng-repeat` with sample array, got the same error