# withFixedColumns property dont work for me using angular datatable

Tags: angularjs, datatables

I am using angulardatable. I need create a table and fixed the first column. Datatable work fine, but when I add withFixedColumns the table dissapear. I have included all libraries.

This is part of my code

```js
var app = angular.module('dataview', ['datatables', 'datatables.fixedcolumns'])

app.controller('DataViewCtrl', function($scope, DTOptionsBuilder,){
  
  $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
    .withOption('scrollY', '500px')
    .withOption('scrollX', '100%')
    .withOption('paging', false)
    .withOption('scrollCollapse', true)
})
```

```html
<script src="/assets/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/vendor/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/vendor/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/plugins/dataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/vendor/angular-datatables/dist/angular-datatables.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/plugins/dataTables/FixedColumns-master/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/vendor/angular-datatables/dist/plugins/fixedcolumns/angular-datatables.fixedcolumns.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="dataview" ng-controller="DataViewCtrl as DVC">
  <table class="table table-striped table-hover" datatable="ng" dt-options="dtOptions">
    <thead>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th ng-repeat='tag_name in tag_names'>{{tag_name}}</th>
    <thead>  
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat='tr in graph_data'>
        <td ng-repeat='td in null2text(tr) track by $index'>{{td}}</td>
      </tr>  
    </tbody>  
  <table>  
</body>
```

So far it works correctly, when I enclose withFixedColumns. Table disappears

This is code with error:

```js
 $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
    .withOption('scrollY', '500px')
    .withOption('scrollX', '100%')
    .withOption('paging', false)
    .withOption('scrollCollapse', true)
    .withFixedColumns({
            leftColumns: 1
        });
```

Comment: sounds a awful lot as [**Angular datatables Fixed Columns undefined is not a function**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31547825/1407478) - impossible to say which files you actually include in which versions, when you refer to them all as "assets" locally based, without version info.

Comment: versions: datatables(1.10.4), angular-datatables(0.4.3), FixedColumns(3.1.0)

fixed error with: .withOption('fixedColumns', {leftColumns: 1}); but I need understand the problem